# How to use Every() to return a new array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to filter out an array against another array, using Every() because Every() loop through an array and stop once it return false. However, I'm trying to make it return the new array from other array and stop once it's false.

For example, I have this word "chance" and this array **vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]**. So I wanted to match every letter in "chance" to this vowels array and extract "ch" and stop if "a" in "chance" match the vowels array.

Here's my code

```
function extract(str) {

  var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  var word = str.split("");
  var newletters = [];
  var firstletter = str[0];

  for (var i = 0; i <= vowels.length; i++) {
    if (firstletter !== vowels[i]) {
      word.every(function(letter){
        if (letter.indexOf(vowels[i]) === -1 ){
        return newletters.push(letter);
        } else {
        return false;
        }
      })

    }
  }

  //return str;
}

console.log(extract("chance"));
```

I couldn't figure out how to make it works to get "ch" in new array.

Comment: every returns a boolean - you can't change how a method works - how about using filter or map instead?

Comment: Yes, I did consider using filter with every but filter loops through all objects in an array. I wanted it to stop looping once it returns false...

Comment: Why not using a regex? `var result = str.match(/^[^aeiou]*/) [0];`.

Comment: Why not a simple for loop ?

Comment: Y is a vowel too btw :)

Comment: @JaromandaX, when I use filter with every, it only returns all consonants, not vowels. `newletters = word.filter(function(letter){
      return vowels.every(function(l){
       return letter !== l;
      });});`

Comment: I didn't say use filter with every ... that would be retarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join vowels and use the resulting string in a regex:

```js
function extract(str) {
  var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)[" + vowels.join("") + "]");
  if (str.match(regex) != null && str != "") {
    console.log(str.match(regex)[1]);
    //newletters.push(str.match(regex)[1]);
  }
}

extract("chance");
```

Comment: What about: `""` and `"tv"`?

Comment: Both `extract("");` (empty string) and `extract("rythm");` (no vowels) throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it.
`every()` function is designed to return a `boolean` for each tested element.
But in it, you could add letters in `newletters` array and then return `true`.
And in case of vowel matching, just return `false` to end the `every()` function.
In this way, at the end of the processing, `newletters` is valued as required.

```
 for (var i = 0; i <= vowels.length; i++) {
    if (firstletter !== vowels[i]) {
      word.every(function(letter){
        if (letter.indexOf(vowels[i]) === -1 ){
            newletters.push(letter);
            return true;
         }             
         return false;            
      })

    }
  }
```